# Routing with Cisco CSR 1000v to Peered VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, cisco-vpn

We're attempting to connect our AWS instances with Verizon Wireless via a VPN. Verizon requires the use of a CSR 1000v (versus an AWS-managed VPN connection). I currently have two separate VPCs setup:

- 10.0.0.0/16 is for the CSR appliance
- 192.168.0.0/16 is for our servers

I have a peering connection between the two VPCs with the route tables for the appropriate subnets configured to route traffic between the VPCs to the peering connection.

I'm admittedly out of my depth, but I can't figure out how to add a route to the CSR appliance to route traffic destined for the 192 network. I can't find the neighbor I would need to create the static route nor can I figure out how to configure something like BGP.

Is what I'm wanting to do possible? I like the idea of having the application servers in a separate VPC from the VPN gateway but if that's not possible, I can live without it.

Answer (score 1):

You could better use Transit VPC approach for routing traffic from both the VPCs.
Note- the Spoke VPCs are not in peering with each other when you use a transit VPC.

https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-single-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, yes this is possible. In fact, the only thing you need to do is configure the subnet routes accordingly to route traffic destined for the peer to the peering connection. I just had neglected to do that, which I suppose is the equivalent of "is it plugged in?"